# Can't put text beside image in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I've been doing HTML and CSS for a few months and as a part of my website I made a joke fake sales website. I am sort of basing it on the Amazon pages, with a picture on the left, a header on the right, and a product description on the right underneath the heading. Now yes I know what you're thinking looking at my code "He hasn't even done anything to his description!", well there's nothing there because I got angry and got rid of my CSS for the description. You can see a class `.description` for putting CSS and whatever there. I've tried floating it to the right (it doesn't work), floating to the right and then using `padding` to push it in a certain direction (it doesn't work), E.T.C. If you want the full code I'll put that at the bottom or something. Please show me how I can get my description under the title?

(For this chunk of code I have removed a few bits that were unnecessary)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>merch for sale</title>
    <style>
      #merch{
        float:right;
        padding-right:100px;
      }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.description{

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <h1>
    <div id="merch">
    Hamsterlover606 merchandise for sale
    </div>
  </h1>
  <div class="description">
    <h3>
      Merchandise for Hamsterlover606.
      <br>
      <br>
      Perfect condition, hardly used. Comes with a t-shirt, a hat, and a pillow.
      <br>
      <br>
    </h3>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[The output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3RhR.png)

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Hamsterlover merch for sale</title>
    <style>
      #merch{
        float:right;
        padding-right:100px;
      }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.description{

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="buy.html">Buy</a>
  <a href="sell.html">Sell</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
  <h1>
    <div id="merch">
    Hamsterlover606 merchandise for sale
    </div>
  </h1>
  <a href="pic1.html" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/d006369a-81f1-413d-a5cd-ce34e241b87c%2F775B0830-9365-46FF-AEF7-66F8939D8617.jpeg?v=1575572530269" height="500"></a>
  <div class="description">
    <h3>
      Merchandise for Hamsterlover606.
      <br>
      <br>
      Perfect condition, hardly used. Comes with a t-shirt, a hat, and a pillow.
      <br>
      <br>
    </h3>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` to order and group your code. Try to think of the elements on your page as different groups in a box, and create a `div` for every group.

To make the `div` with the text appear right next to the image, make the image `float: left`.

```
`    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hamsterlover merch for sale</title>
        <style>
            #merch{

            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            .topnav {
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333;
            }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

            .topnav a:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
                color: black;
            }

            .topnav a.active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
            }

            #img {
                float: left;
            }

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="buy.html">Buy</a>
            <a href="sell.html">Sell</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
        <div id="img">
            <a href="pic1.html" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/d006369a-81f1-413d-a5cd-ce34e241b87c%2F775B0830-9365-46FF-AEF7-66F8939D8617.jpeg?v=1575572530269" height="500"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>
                Hamsterlover606 merchandise for sale
            </h1>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>
                    Merchandise for Hamsterlover606.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Perfect condition, hardly used. Comes with a t-shirt, a hat, and a pillow.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
```